# Probability of Chosing a King Next

Tags: probability

An ordinary deck of playing cards is shuffled and the top card set aside without knowing its face value. What is the probability that the next card is a king?

P(king)= $3/51$....I am stuck because I am assuming the first card I Put down is/not a king determines the chance the at my next card is a king. Either way I know my sample is 51 but were Am I going wrong?

Comment: Here is a well-mixed deck of cards. What is the probability that the top card is a king? What is the probability that the bottom card is a king? What is the probability that the 17th card from the top is a king? ***What is the probability that the 2nd card from the top is a king?*** Do you really think kings are more likely to turn up is some positions that in others?

Comment: Let $p_1$ be the probability that the second card dealt is an ace, $p_2$ the probability that it's a deuce, $p_3$ the probability that it's a trey, and so on, so that $p_{13}$ is the probability that it's a king. Are we agreed that those $13$ probabilities add up to $1?$ Now, do you think the probabilities are all equal? Or do you think some of those events are more likely than others?

Comment: I've shuffled the deck and I'm about to deal a card. The probability that I'm going to deal a king is $1/13,$ right? But wait, the player next to me wants to cut the cards. He cuts, ***moving an unknown number of kings to the lower part of the deck.*** ***Now*** what's the probability of dealing a king??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the card is a king, and that has $\frac{4}{52}$ probability, then the probability that the next card is a king is $\frac{3}{51}$ as you correctly identified. But, if the card is not a king, and that has $\frac{48}{52}$ probability, then the probability the next card is a king is $\frac{4}{51}$. Hence the answer by the law of total probability is,

$$\frac{4}{52}(\frac{3}{51})+\frac{48}{52}(\frac{4}{51})$$

$$=\frac{4(3)+4(48)}{51(52)}$$

$$=\frac{4(3+48)}{51(52)}$$

$$=\frac{4}{52}$$

Comment: ... *which simplified is equal to* $\frac{4}{52}$

Answer (score 2):

It's 4/52, as you don't know the value of the first card.

Think of it this way--there are 52 cards in front of you and all you know is 4 of them are kings and 48 are not.

You can also calculate directly using conditional probability:

$P(King On Second Card)=P(King On Second Card|King On First Card)\cdot P(King On First Card) + P(King On Second Card|Not King On First Card)\cdot P(Not King On First Card)=\frac 3 {51}\cdot \frac 4 {52} + \frac 4 {51}\cdot \frac {48} {52}$